# Can you use multiple fetches in one loader with createBrowserRouter react-router v6, and use the fetched data just with useLoaderData, not useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to put multiple fetches into one loader, using React Router v6 with `createBrowserRouter` and MongoDB.  I would like to call three different database collections on one page, for example "stores", "departments", and "items".  I'm currently using .populate to get departments and items into the stores collection, but it returns a huge json file.  Also I have to manually add the id's into arrays for departments and items.  Seems like it would be easier to just fetch those off a query for store id.

Also, there may be other times when I'm working with pages that need data from two completely different APIs, for example bringing in weather data or google maps, so I want to figure out how to do multiple fetches in one single loader.

For this particular example, I'm thinking something like what I have below, but I don't know how to return multiple json objects.  I've tried importing `json` from `react-router-dom` but am not having any luck.

```js
export const storeLoader = async ({ params }) => {
  const [store, departments, items] = await Promise.all([
    fetch("/stores/" + params.id),
    fetch("/departments/?store=" + params.id),
    fetch("/items/?store=" + params.id),
  ]);
  return { store, departments, items }
  // meaning stores.json(), departments.json(), items.json()
}
```

Then, using `useLoaderData` as follows:

```js
const Store = () => {
  const { store, departments, items } = useLoaderData();
```